# Syntax error in Gii generated Search Model in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have generated a search model for a table called `vast_table` using Gii tool.
However I have a syntax error in the Gii generated model which is perfectly fine.
The error is :

```
PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException

syntax error, unexpected ']'
```

My search model looks like this :

```
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Ad', $this->Ad])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Collapse', $this->Collapse])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'CloseLinear', $this->CloseLinear])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Skip', $this->Skip])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Played10%', $this->Played10%])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Played30%', $this->Played30%])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Played40%', $this->Played40%])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Played60%', $this->Played60%]);
```

The error is pointing to the last four lines. What should I do please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the percent sign '%' is the [modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator in php

while you may be able to define a db column as `Played60%`, php wont allow you to put special characters in variable names

you may either rename those columns to something like `Played60p` or manually adjust the model properties that have been generated by gii to be syntactically correct.

additionally here's the schema design [guideline](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/227/guidelines-for-good-schema-design/) yii provides